# SQL Developer Shortcuts

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer to connect to an Oracle DB.

I would like to be able to see the constraints of a table via the command window. Usually I have to navigate the tables tree and then open the table details. Is there a shortcut to allow me to access the constraints (in particular the FK constraints) by writing a command? Ideally I want something like

```
desc table_name
```

where desc describes the table. I know desc is SQL based but are there any commands I can use within SQL developer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can browse for the table in table browser under your connection. Open it. You can find a constraints tab where you can find the information about constraints on the table. Instead you can click on table name in command window (the worksheet) press the shortcut `Shift +F4` which will give the same information.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked here:

http://p2p.wrox.com/oracle/30730-sp_help-equivalent-oracle.html

Someone suggested:

`select * from user_constraints where table_name=[yourtable]`

There are other suggestions too...

Answer (score 0):

The following select command will show the table details in Oracle

```
Select * from user_tables 
where table_name='COUNTRIES'
```

Another solution to see the description of table in Oracle, on sql> prompt

```
SQL>Description Countries
```

or

```
SQL>Desc Countries
```

This will show the column name and datatype as well as constraints.